# can we convert a variable data into variable

Tags: java

```
boolean isdata=false; // converting this to true
String qname="data";
String abc="is"+qname;
isdata = true // works here but i dont wanna hard code.. there is much data like this
               // i am trying to automate the process. i have basic knowledge of doing it manually
```

but i want to convert isdata to true now. Is there any implementation for this.

Comment: do you want something like this `boolean isdata = false; /* Do some stuff */ isdata = true;`

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: It seems the answer to the immediate question is [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).  But it would pay to look at the overall design, since something that requires reflection is usually a bad design.

Comment: why cant you do `isdata=true`?

Comment: i am trying to automate the process.. and create a variable with is before the inputdata

Comment: @prashanth I quite enjoy watching you adding more texts to your question but they all don't make your question any clearer.

Comment: @gigadot - It looks like the OP's after something like PHP's [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: do you want to create new variables based on user input ? i.e. if the user enters `garbage` create a new variable called `isgarbage` ? what exactly are you trying to accomplish? ... if this is what you want maybe [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) could help

Comment: @RobHruska i was trying for the one you had mentioned in php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're after something like PHP's [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which Java doesn't support (without using [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), anyway).

If you must do it this way, you might as well just use a `Map`. Since you want to prefix everything with "is", I'm assuming they'll all be `Boolean`s.

```
Map<String, Boolean> is = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

...

String qname = "data";
is.put(qname, false);

...

// retrieve is[data] for comparison
if (is.containsKey("data") && is.get("data")) {
    // is[data] is true
}

// update is[data]
is.put("data", true);
```

Honestly though, if you're doing something like this, the way you've designed it is probably a bit klunky. You might step back and see if you can improve it.